# unable to change option of a select menu with custom select event handler

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, clone, select-menu

in the following call function `onSelectEvent:` is responsible for handling & switching the option. i'm trying to get the option value through this variable but this variable in call function  freezes the options of select menu.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
    var selectEvent = function($el){
        $(".selectmenu").change(function() {
            var selectedValue = $("select.selectmenu").val(); 
            alert('Selected event' + selectEvent);
        });
    };
    $(".selectmenu").scrollectBox({                           
        preset: 'dropdown',
        numVisibleOptions: 4,
        scrollInterval: 150, 
        scrollOn: 'hover',
        listWidth: 160,
        onSelectEvent: selectEvent  
   });
});
```

the code may be wrong but how can i write similar syntax correctly.

thanks,

**EDIT:**

Plugin Urls:

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/index.html

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/js/ScrollectBox/jquery.scrollectbox.js

```
<div id = "translate">
     <select onchange="Translate(this)" name="select" id="translator" class="selectmenu" >
     <option value="Select Language">Select Language</option>
     <option value="en|af">Afrikaans</option>
     <option value="en|sq">Albanian</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var selectEvent = function($el){
     console.log($el);
     var selectedValue = $el.html(); 
     alert(selectedValue);return false;
};
```

Or if you want the `change event` then try

```
var selectEvent = function($el){
    console.log($el);
    $el.change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).html(); 
        alert('Selected value' + selectedValue);// I think its value not event
    });
};
```

Comment: unfortunately 1st block of code can't extract the value. it alerts blank popup. 2nd block of code makes the options non clickable.thanks,

Comment: First check whether you get the `element` or not by `console.log($el);` and change `val()` to `html()`. Check the above answer I have changed it.

Comment: first block of code returns option text `Afrikaans` but not the actual option value `en|af`. i've edited my question. the plugin links are included in my edited question.

Comment: What you get by `console.log($el);`?

Comment: i implemented your code at http://silentpond.eu5.org/ScrollectBoxDemo/ScrollectBoxDemo/cloned-select-menu.html you can inspect the result there. what exactly you want to know about `console.log($el);`? if necessary i can provide you my ftp details.